# Overcome 2GB limit on XML output in SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012, large-data

There is a daily process that produces an XML file from an SQL Server database.

Internally it is implemented as a series of nested "FOR XML..." queries enclosed in a stored procedure. A Powershell script executes the stored procedure and processes the output.

Recently, the amount of data generated by the stored procedure exceeded 2 GB and the process died because of a hard limit on XML data type size in SQL Server.

My question is, what would be the best approach to bypass that limit? Obviously, using the XML data type in SQL Server is a no-go but I guess people somehow *do* generate large XML files off SQL Server databases.

Comment: LOBs are limited to 2GB. I think you will have to work this down in steps...

Comment: Please share your stored procedure. It is possible that the bcp command line utility will be able to generate XML large than 2GB file

Comment: Usually, data feeds could be split into multiple files for manageability, testing, and easier transfer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the sproc code. It generates an xml with a single root, 3 1st level, 8 2nd level and ~800K 3rd level nested data. It uses various #temptables with indexes, grouping, sorting and other stuf. Around 80% of the volume is covered with one particular set of 3rd level nodes (700K nodes in total). I guess I could split the node into multiple chunks then merge (as text) them outside SQL Server instance (with some command line / Powershell utility) but that's cumbersome. I am looking for possibly simple solution that wouldn't require me to re-engineer the whole thing.

Comment: SQL Server has 2GB limit on variables and columns of XML data type. Are you using them in the stored procedure?

Comment: I am. The entire procedure is logically split into two stages. The fIrst one prepares data as a set of indexed #temptables. The second one is a SELECT... statement with plenty of nested subselects / CTEs, each terminated with "FOR XML PATH... ROOT...". The outermost query is also a FOR XML... one.

Comment: Still not clear. I don't see any XML variables and/or XML columns in your explanation. Please try to generate XML file via bcp calling the same stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please adjust it to test in your environment at the command prompt. It is using Windows Authentication.

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" "EXEC DBNAME.dbo.usp_name;" queryout "e:\Temp\XMLOutput.xml" -T -x -c -C 1252 -a 32768 -S "DBServerName,1433"
```

Comment: This is absolutely embarrasing. It seems the problem with data exceeding 2GB limit is a false alarm. For some reason, SSMS reports the output to be 2GB+ but when I run the same stored procedure via BCP (as in your example), I am only getting 220MB output xml data which means there is no problem in the first place. I am leaving this as a valid answer though should anyone else face a similar issue.

Comment: A couple of things to be aware of: (1) use -w in place of -c to get it working with Unicode data then (2) be aware that bcp generates files with BOM (FF-FE) which may need to be removed downstream if needed, finally (3) use -r option to avoid random line breaks in the middle of an XML tag. Other than that the method works perfectly well.